# How to exclude binary file from remote git repo?

Tags: git

I commited and pushed binary file to git repo. Actually I don't wan't this file in git repo, I was needed to add it to LFS.

So, firstly question is - how to exclude this file from remote git tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add it to your `.gitignore` file and don't forget to commit the file :-)

   - You can use this site: http://gtiignore.io to generate the `.gitignore` for you and add the required path to your binary files/folder(s)
2. Once you added the file to `.gitignore` you can remove the "old" binary file with BFG.

#### Important:

Since the file is already tracked by git, unless you will remove it from history (ex. BFG) you need to remove it manually and commit your changes.

---

## ***`How to remove big files from the repository`***

You can use `git filter-branch` or BFG. 
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

> #### `BFG Repo-Cleaner`
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> *** Removing Crazy Big Files***
>   * Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]